how to use IMFTransform convert NV12 to m3u8 ts file?
I can read camera which is NV12 data.
and transform it to m3u8 's ts files?
one m3u8 file is 1s to 3s each.

m3u8 is a media playlist file - NV12 as a binary image format. You cannot convert between them: they represent entirely different things.

@Dai  what about NV12 to *.ts ?  what I want is to capture the desktop and then make it as live video. other can get the desktop using the m3u8 url

.ts is a container format, not a codec.

@Dai thank you . and can you tell me what should me search for when I want to convert the NV12 to ts files?


how to use IMFTransform...

Microsoft Media Foundation Transforms are primitives typically for one single task. In your scanerio there is a transform to convert NV12 video into another uncomressed format, or to compress to typically H.264/AVC. This is the task of one transform and it is not supposed to do magic of giving you something that much more sophisticated as live HLS stream.
To obtain .ts media segmetns to serve as a part of HLS transmission you need H.264/AVC compression mentioned above, then you also need MPEG TS multiplexer, for which Microsoft does not¹ offer you a stock primitive, which would/could rather be a Microsoft Media Foundation Sink instead.
Then you would connect all this into something like Media Session topology or you would use Sink Writer API, or Transcoding API, and then you would be able to convert raw video into HLS compatible MPEG TS media segmetn for HTML5 media streaming.
--
¹ There is something like MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG2 but Microsoft does not document it so I doubt it is usable - or maybe you will find a way and share it with others

I convert raw video into HLS compatible MPEG TS. is the MPEG TS need to be encode by IMFTransform? so it's size can be small?
that is what I am thinking. you know in IMFTransform it will generate each frame using the first frame(the difference) and does TS need to be re-generate for each frame?
